# Dynamic Reply based on String in a Row

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and 500 rows and I want to use a function data$GDP based on if a dataframe row in COMBO contains "pmi23". I do it in a loop so in the first loop, if row 1 contains "pmi23" at either column 1,2,3, a function TEST should be carried on (that is, data$GDP times the logical test that returns 1). What R function can return 1 for me in such a case?

MY DATA was created through:

```
library(plyr)

Comb1 <- CombSet(c("pmi23","yc23","debt23","st23","pmiyc","pmidebt","pmist","ycdebt","ycst","debtst"), c(1), repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE, as.list = FALSE)
Comb2 <- CombSet(c("pmi23","yc23","debt23","st23","pmiyc","pmidebt","pmist","ycdebt","ycst","debtst"), c(2), repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE, as.list = FALSE)
Comb3 <- CombSet(c("pmi23","yc23","debt23","st23","pmiyc","pmidebt","pmist","ycdebt","ycst","debtst"), c(3), repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE, as.list = FALSE)

Comb1 <- as.data.frame(Comb1)
Comb2 <- as.data.frame(Comb2) 
Comb3 <- as.data.frame(Comb3)

COMBO <- rbind.fill(Comb1,Comb2,Comb3)
```

For some reason, `"pmi23" %in% DATA[1,]` does not work while `"pmi23" %in% DATA[1,1]` does so I need either an OR test for all rows or an alternative.

Comment: `dput`? `Expected output`?

Comment: @MAPK either a data$GDP or 0

Comment: Try `DATA[,1] %in% "pmi23"`.